# Cannot read property 'main_text_matched_substrings' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

first I fetch the location and then select the text box field using the mouse. and then clear the location. But after clear the location, it shows an error.

**Cannot read property 'main_text_matched_substrings' of undefined**

[image]

[image]

```
 renderOption={(option) => {
              const matches =
                option.structured_formatting.main_text_matched_substrings;
              const parts = parse(
                option.structured_formatting.main_text,
                matches.map((match) => [match.offset, match.offset + match.length])
              );
    
              return (
                <Grid container alignItems="center">
                  <Grid item>
                    <LocationOnIcon className={classes.icon} />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    {parts.map((part, index) => (
                      <span
                        key={index}
                        style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
                      >
                        {part.text }
                      </span>
                    ))}
    
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                      {option.structured_formatting.secondary_text}
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              );
            }}
```

here is full code [code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-wave-8on0k?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Seems you didn't pass in option.structured_formatting

Comment: it means `option.structured_formatting` is `undefined` - where is this options object defined?

Comment: Or use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Comment: here is the full code https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-wave-8on0k?file=/src/App.js @AlwaysLearning

Comment: add some console.log to see what the option value is inside of the renderOption function. It obviously isn't what you think it looks like

Answer (score 3):

Material UI has updated the Places autocomplete component as part of the upgrade to version 5. You'll get this error if you leave your v4 (working) code in place, which appears to have been copied verbatim from the v4 docs.

The critical part of the problem is that the renderOption func is now called with two params: `(props, option)`. So your `option` is all wrong, and missing `structured_formatting` amongst other things.

Best is to go back to the docs and use the new renderOption function in their example.

https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#GoogleMaps.js

Comment: I'm getting this same error while migrating from muiv4 to muiv5. This answer helped me along, but the muiv5 component doesn't quite work yet. I'll add more when I discover what else I have to do. I think this should be an "Accepted" answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you didn't handle empty cases in your Autocomplete component(the one in the sandbox). Initially, it works because you have options thanks to your initialisation, so option.structured_formatting exists and is not undefined. However, when you are clearing it out, it is becoming undefined, and undefined doesn't have a structured_formatting field, so javascript is throwing an error. To fix this, put an if condition which checks if(option.structured_formatting) to see if it exists and is not null. However, from your code,I suspect that option itself is becoming null, so you might want to add another check for that(like if(option)). Depending on the behaviour you desire, you can write the else blocks for them accordingly.